# How do I return values from an asynchronous call in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a C# form that I've talking to from another thread, using the `Invoke` methodology detailed on MSDN. Invoking the method on the main thread works, and here's a snippet of the basic structure:

```
// In the main thread:
public void doCommand(int arg, out int ret) {
    ret = arg + 1;
}

// On another thread:
public delegate void CmdInvoke(int arg, out int ret);

public void execute() {
    CmdInvoke d = new CmdInvoke(Program.form.doCommand);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    Program.form.Invoke(d, new object[] { a, b });

    // I want to use b now...
}
```

As described above, I now want to return the parameter `b` back to the calling thread. At the moment, `b` is always `0`. I've read that maybe I need to use `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`, but I'm a bit confused to be honest How can I get at `b`? I don't mind if it's an `out` parameter or a `return`, I just want it somehow!

Comment: Can you use a `Func<T>` ?

Comment: You're using the wrong tools. State the versions you use. C#5 ?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?  If you have a background thread doing some work and you're calling Invoke to update the UI, why does the UI update need to send information back to the long running task?  It's a very unusual requirement to begin with.

Comment: Oh, and for the record, this call isn't asynchronous at all.

Comment: I don't know what version I'm using and I'm away from the office now so can't check - what do you mean I'm using the wrong tools?

Comment: Servy - because I'm actioning it from a server I've created and I need to send information generated by the UI back to it. Asynchronous or not, how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the updated value from `doCommand` in such a way (return new value in the ordinary way with `return` not as an `out` parameter):

```
// In the main thread:
public int doCommand(int arg) {
    return arg + 1;
}

// On another thread:
public delegate int CmdInvoke(int arg);

public void execute() {
    CmdInvoke d = new CmdInvoke(Program.form.doCommand);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    b = (int)Program.form.Invoke(d, new object[] { a });
    // Now b is 1
}
```

An `out` parameter doesn't work because when you put `b` into the array `object[]` the copy of `b` is actually contained in the array (because of [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)). And consequently method `doCommand` changes that copy not the original `b` variable.